# JQuery: Binding the .validate plugin to .live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to bind the [jQuery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to forms that I generate on the fly.  As far as I know `.live()` is the only way to do this in jQuery.  It doesn't seem to work, at least the way I'm trying.  I think this is do'able and it's just eebkac!

This works Fine:

```
$("form#form_CreateUser").validate({  
   submitHandler: function(form) {  
    // do other stuff for a valid form  
    UserSubmit();  
   }  
});
```

This generates syntax errors:

```
$("form#form_CreateUser").live('validate', function() {  
   submitHandler: function(form) {  
    // do other stuff for a valid form  
    UserSubmit(); 
   }  
});
```

Comment: Please do not use URL shorteners on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14):

This doesn't work because you've misunderstood how `validate` works.  It *looks* like event handler functions like `click`, but it actually is not.

`click` is a shortcut for `bind('click', fn)`.  `validate` does not work by using `bind`.  Since `live` is effectively a way of making `bind` calls work on elements that don't yet exist, it doesn't work with `validate`.

The easiest way of doing this is to make a function that calls `validate` and call that function every time you insert new content. For instance, if you are inserting the form using AJAX, you could use the `ajaxComplete` function:

```
function setupValidate() {
    $("form#form_CreateUser").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            UserSubmit();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ajaxComplete(setupValidate); // after every AJAX request
setupValidate(); // right now
```